# Divide derived rank, count columns from subquery to find percentile

Tags: sql-server-2005, percentile

I'm having trouble dividing two columns from a subquery.  The only answer that's returned is 0.  I've tried multiplying the two columns just to see if it works and it does.  I cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
SELECT cert, repdte, NAMEFULL, Rnk, Cnt, (Cnt - Rnk) / Cnt as 'Perc'
FROM
(
    SELECT STRU.cert, STRU.repdte, STRU.NAMEFULL,
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE (ISNULL(INC.EINTEXPA,0) / ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0))*100
    END AS 'CoF', RANK() OVER (Partition by STRU.repdte ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE (ISNULL(INC.EINTEXPA,0) / ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0))*100
    END DESC) AS 'Rnk', COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STRU.repdte) as 'Cnt'
    FROM MODEL_RIS_RMS_FDIC.dbo.STRU as STRU
    JOIN MODEL_RIS_FDIC.dbo.CDI_RC_BAL as BAL
        ON STRU.cert = BAL.cert AND STRU.callYMD = BAL.callYMD
    JOIN MODEL_RIS_FDIC.dbo.CDI_RI_INC as INC
    ON STRU.cert = INC.cert and STRU.callYMD = INC.callYMD
    WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE (ISNULL(INC.EINTEXPA,0) / ISNULL(BAL.DEPI5,0))*100
    END IS NOT NULL AND STRU.callYMD >= '2008-03-31'
) A
WHERE Perc < .11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the datatypes of Cnt and Rnk are INT and hence the result gives you the least value of INT type which is 0. Try casting Cnt and Rnk to FLOAT

```
(cast(Cnt - Rnk) as FLOAT)/CAST(Cnt as FLOAT)
```